# Better way to create list consisting only of zeros

Tags: r, list

Is there a more elegant way to create a list consisting only of zeros (I don't want to use `vector("list", <len>)` because it creates NULL entries)?

```
lapply((1:5), function(x) 0)
```

(Sorry, this is probably a duplicate, but I couldn't find the answer ..)

Thx & kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `as.list` with `numeric` or `integer`

```
as.list(numeric(5))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rep` like this

```
rep(0,5)
```

Comment: This will not be a list.